# Prevent private key exposure using custom openssl engine

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12, sslengine

Is it possible to have an engine generate a keypair, have the application 'use' the private key (e.g. to sign) WITHOUT actually exposing the key ? E.g. openssl would return some kind of reference but not the key itself.
Moreover there should be a way to store the keypair (and any associated certificate chains) and retrieve them later. We were thinking of storing everything in a pkcs12 struct.

Could you give me some pointers how to do this in C ?

Comment: Do you mean something like Windows Certificate store when key is not marked as exportable, only its reference can be obtained and not exported but can be used for signing?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using a Hardware Security Module (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_Security_Module) supported by OpenSSL.

I have successfully used nCipher HSM with OpenSSL in the past, but they are not the only supported vendor.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Which openssl api calls do I use to store the x509 certificates I have obtained from the CA ? Of course I want to maintain the link with the private key...